# Got message 'failed to update trigger' and 'failed to disable trigger' when trying to save/disable Google Cloud Build

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-build

I got this errors recently:

[image: Failed to Update trigger error]

and this...
[image: Failed to disable trigger error]

This is applied to all of my cloud build triggers even saving without changing anything. The triggers still running fine. I can create new trigger but not with editing. Unfortunately no further error code or anything.

I am not sure this is related or not, but I changed IAM recently where I click "Recommended role replacement"

[image]

Any explaination for this?

Comment: could you check your assigned roles in IAM? you should be something like "admin". 
It really feels like an error related to rights

Comment: my account is the Owner and nothing changed. my last recommended role changes were applied to my subordinate account and I have reverted that back. but still no luck

Comment: It would be nice if you could get more information on the error as it is not very informative currently. You can check it Logging sections under Cloud Build. If there is nothing maybe you can try to edit trigger using [API](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/patch) and see if it also fails it might give more details on actual error.